# What is the best practice to update 2 collections in the nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have 2 collections. `User` Model and `Organization` Model.

A user schema is something like this

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
  },
  organizationId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Organization",
  })
```

As you can see a user can be included in 1 organization.

But let say we are launching a new database. So when `creating` new user there is no `organization` exist yet.

Here what I wanna ask.

When creating new organization.

1. Should i call save 2 times in a roll like this or
2. After saving organization. Should i update the user with different api end point

Which one is the better practice

```
  router.post("/organizations", auth, async (req, res) => {
      const organization = new Organization(req.body);
      //req.user will send user data
      const user = req.user;
      user.organizationId = organization._id;
    
      try {
        await organization.save();
        await user.save();
        res.send(organization);
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    });
```